# Why taking integral of both sides of matrix inequality is allowed?

Tags: integration, matrices, positive-semidefinite

How to show if $\nabla^2 f(x) \succeq \alpha I$, then the function is $\alpha$-strongly convex?

In my optimization notes I have 
$$\nabla^2 f(x) \succeq \alpha I \rightarrow \alpha\text{-strongly convex} \,\,\,\,\,\,\forall x$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\succeq B$ means $A-B$ is positive semi-definite.

For the proof we use mean value theorem
$$
\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(y) = \int_0^1 \nabla^2 f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)dt
$$
where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $0 \leq t \leq 1$.
$$
\langle \nabla f(y)-\nabla f(y) ,y-x \rangle= \langle \int_0^1 \nabla^2 f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)dt,y-x \rangle
$$
Since
$$\nabla^2 f(x+t(y-x)) \succeq \alpha I \tag{1}$$
and the fact that $\langle Ad,d \rangle \geq c\|d\|^2 \leftrightarrow A \succeq cI \tag{2}$

$$
\langle \int_0^1 \nabla^2 f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)dt,y-x \rangle \geq \alpha \|y-x\|^2 \tag{3}
$$
I do not understand why how we can use $(1)$ to get $(2)$? Because I do not know why we can use $(1)$ and write
$$
A=\int_0^1 \nabla^2 f(x+t(y-x))dt \succeq \int_0^1 \alpha I dt= \alpha I
$$
and then use $(2)$.

Is it possible to take integral from any matrix inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your statement of the "mean value theorem" and in other parts of your post, you are taking the integral of a vector or a matrix, which does not make sense.

I think it would be better to state the integral equality as
$$\langle \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle
= \int_0^1 \langle \nabla^2 f(x + t(y-x)) (y-x), y-x \rangle \, dt.$$
(This is simply the fundamental theorem of calculus $g(1) - g(0) = \int_0^1 g'(t) \, dt$ applied to $g(t) := \langle \nabla f(x + t(y-x)), y-x \rangle$.)

From here, you can immediately use
$\nabla^2 f(x + t(y-x)) (y-x), y-x \rangle \ge \alpha \|y-x\|^2$ from (2), as desired.